# Setting weights to model from another one with additional layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was trying to update weights in Keras model(let it be model A).

Weights are given from another model (model B- it's an extension of model A, two extra layers at the end) which is in training loop process(train_on_batch), im updating weights using method:

```
modelA.set_weights(modelB.get_weights())
```

And surprisingly it worked (the process run), even if network's architectures are different. How's that possible? Is set_weights() automatically cutting of additional part of weights? Or something is wrong and updated weight are mixed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `set_weights` method loads a list of float regarding of the layers' name.

[image]

What you might be looking for is the `load_weights` method with argument `by_name=True` ([documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#savingloading-only-a-models-weights))

Comment: Thank's it's working and i'm sure the weight are not mixed up.